# mysqlhotcopy on a db with name with non-alphanumeric chars

Tags: mysql, backup

If I do (in MySQL 5.1.59)

```
mysql> create database `db-name`;
```

the resulting directory name on the file system is `db@002dname`. Normally this is not a problem but I have found that `mysqlhotcopy` won't work if I invoke it like this:

```
$ mysqlhotcopy db-name ~/db-name
Cannot open dir '/var/db/mysql/db-name': No such file or directory
```

Do I have to translate the database name to `db@002dname` and use that as the DB name when I invoke mysqlhotcopy?

[The algorithm](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-mapping.html), btw, is shocking. If the untranslated name is ASCII then it's not too bad.

Comment: tried escaping it with a backslash?

Comment: Why not just using underscore instead?

Comment: escaping with backslash doesn't help

Comment: Khaled—because the database name has a hyphen in it, not an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to translate the database name to db@002dname and use that as the DB name when I invoke mysqlhotcopy?

That won't work; it's a bug in `mysqlhotcopy` -- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44278 -- and it's still open.  There's a patch, though -- http://lists.mysql.com/commits/80079